# How are Python Dictionaries indexed in neo4j

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, neo4j, bulbs

Bulbflow provides a property class Dictionary to store dictionaries in a neo4j database. How are these indexed? Can I query it for values in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j does not support dicts/maps, only primitives and primitive arrays. For Neo4j, you can use the Bulbs `Document` `Property` to have the Python `dict` converted and stored in Neo4j as a JSON string , and Bulbs will automatically convert it back into a Python `dict` when you retrieve it. It will be indexed as a string in Neo4j.

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/property.py#L456